# How can I change 24 hour time format to 12 hour format using if and else?

Tags: python

Example if we type 0010 then it should display 12:10 AM like that for every number it should display.,

Comment: Please re-take the [tour] and read [ask]. Explain your problem with enough details so others can understand. Give examples of input and output. *Show your own attempts.*

Comment: Is there some reason you need to use if and else instead of Python's `strftime()` and `strptime()` functions? https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 1):

```
military_times = ['0010', '0125', '1159', '1200', '1201',
'1259', '1344', '1959', '2359']

for item in military_times:
    # time is between 0000 and 0059
    if int(item[0: 2]) == 0:
        t = '12:' + item[2: 4] + ' AM'

    # time is between 1:00 am and 9:59 am
    elif int(item[0: 2]) > 0 and int(item[0: 2]) <= 9:
        t = str(item[1: 2]) + ':' + item[2: 4] + ' AM'

    # time is between 10:00 am and 11:59 am
    elif int(item[0: 2]) > 0 and int(item[0: 2]) <= 11:
        t = str(item[0: 2]) +  ':' + item[2: 4] + ' AM'

    # time is between 12:00 pm and 12:59 pm
    elif int(item[0: 2]) > 0 and int(item[0: 2]) == 12:
        t = str(item[0: 2]) +  ':' + item[2: 4] + ' PM'

    # time is between 12:00 pm and 11:59 pm
    else:
        t = str(int(item[0: 2]) - 12) + ':' + item[2: 4] + ' PM'

    print t

'''
# output
12:10 AM
1:25 AM
11:59 AM
12:00 PM
12:01 PM
12:59 PM
1:44 PM
7:59 PM
11:59 PM
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_12_hour(ts):
    hr = int(ts[:2])
    mins = int(ts[-2:])

    return "{0}:{1}{2}".format(hr, mins, 'AM' if hr < 12 else 'PM')
```